# filtering data by excluding particular data based on condition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I want to check the record in list based on trackId and InUse property because I want the unique data which has Inuse property = false but I want to exclude the record of Track="S" how do I exlude that so my condition does not check the record that has Track="S" because SidList also contains the record with track="S". Below is my condition

```
if (SidList.Any(q => q.TrackId == item.TrackId && q.InUse == true))

            {
               //Not unique logic goes here
            }
```

I tried this condtion but it does not work

```
if (SidList.Any(q => q.TrackId == item.TrackId && q.InUse == true && !q.Track.Contains('S')))

            {
            }
```

Comment: What exactly is it you're looking for? A unique list (like a distinct function)?

Comment: No Something like if (SidList.Any(q => q.TrackId == item.TrackId && q.InUse == true && !q.Track.Contains('S')))

                {
                }

Comment: Your requirement is that `InUse` property is set to `false` but you're checking `q.InUse == true`  in your LINQ statement?

Comment: I suggest that you could provide the model for us.And I have doubt that you don't want Track contains S or Track equals S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string.Contains` is case sensitive.If `Track` has data with lower case `s`,the statement `!q.Track.Contains('S')` will return true.

If you want to ignore the case,change like below:

```
!q.Track.Contains('S', StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Here is the whole working demo:

Model:

```
public class TrackModel
{
    public int TrackId { get; set; }
    public bool InUse { get; set; }
    public string Track { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
var SidList = new List<TrackModel>() {
    new TrackModel(){TrackId=1,InUse=false,Track="dfdfds"}
};

if (SidList.Any(q => q.TrackId == 1 && q.InUse == false&& !q.Track.Contains('S', StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
    //...
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredList = SidList.Where(q => q.TrackId == item.TrackId && q.InUse && !q.Track.Contains('S'))
foreach ( var filteredElement in filteredList)
{
     // not unique action goes here
}
```

Comment: This could be a great answer, but better suited if you would you consider doing an [edit] to the post to provide some context and quick detail (in plain English) as to why you suggested this as the OP's solution?

Comment: if OP just wants to check if any, then if(filteredList.Count>0) is sufficient